# ELF INIT section code to prepopulate objects used at runtime

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, elf, dynamic-linking

I'm fairly new to c++ and am really interested in learning more. Have been reading quite a bit.  Recently discovered the init/fini elf sections.
I started to wonder if & how one would use the init section to prepopulate objects that would be used at runtime.  Say for example you wanted
to add performance measurements to your code, recording the time, filename, linenumber, and maybe some ID (monotonic increasing int for ex) or name.
You would place for example:

```
PROBE(0,"EventProcessing",__FILE__,__LINE__)
...... //process event
PROBE(1,"EventProcessing",__FILE__,__LINE__)
......//different processing on same event
PROBE(2,"EventProcessing",__FILE__,__LINE__)
```

The PROBE could be some macro that populates a struct containing this data (maybe on an array/list, etc using the id as an indexer).
Would it be possible to have code in the init section that could prepopulate all of this data for each PROBE (except for the time of course), so only the time would need to be retrieved/copied at runtime?

As far as I know the `__attribute__((constructor))` can not be applied to member functions?

My initial idea was to create some kind of 
linked list with each node pointing to each probe and code in the init secction could iterate it populating the id, file, line, etc, but 
that idea assumed I could use a member function that could run in the "init" section, but that does not seem possible.  Any tips appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand it, you do not actually need an ELF constructor here.  Instead, you could emit descriptors for your probes using [extended `asm` statements](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) (using data, instead of code).  This also involves switching to a dedicated ELF section for the probe descriptors, say `__probes`.

The linker will concatenate all the probes and in an array, and generate special symbols `__start___probes` and `__stop___probes`, which you can use from your program to access thes probes. See the last paragraph in [Input Section Example](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.31/ld/Input-Section-Example.html).

[Systemtap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/) implements something quite similar for its userspace probes:

- [User Space Probe Implementation](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/wiki/UserSpaceProbeImplementation)
- [Adding User Space Probing to an Application (heapsort example)](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/wiki/AddingUserSpaceProbingToApps)

Similar constructs are also used within the Linux kernel for its self-patching mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty simple way to have code run on module load time: Use the constructor of a global variable:

```
struct RunMeSomeCode
{
  RunMeSomeCode()
  {
    // your code goes here
  }
} do_it;
```

The `.init`/`.fini` sections basically exist to implement global constructors/destructors as part of the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) on some platforms. Other platforms may use different mechanisms such as `_start` and `_init` functions or `.init_array`/`.deinit_array` and `.preinit_array`. There are lots of subtle differences between all these methods and which one to use for what is a question that can really only be answered by the documentation of your target platform. Not all platforms use ELF to begin with…

The main point to understand is that things like the `.init`/`.fini` sections in an ELF binary happen way below the level of C++ as a language. A C++ compiler may use these things to implement certain behavior on a certain target platform. On a different platform, a C++ compiler will probably have to use different mechanisms to implement that same behavior. Many compilers will give you tools in the form of language extensions like `__attributes__` or `#pragmas` to control such platform-specific details. But those generally only make sense and will only work with that particular compiler on that particular platform.

Comment: that I understand.. What I'm asking is how can I populate each PROBE in a file before main, with an increasing ID, __FILE__,__LINE__, etc?  How can I get access to each declared PROBE  in the code?

Comment: What exactly should such a `PROBE` be? A global object? The problem is that there's not really a simple mechanism for anything to do with working across multiple separate translation units at compile time. Do the IDs have to be increasing numbers? One simple way to just get an ID that is guaranteed unique would be to simply use the address of a global object or function.

Comment: Oh, you meant `PROBEs` in the same file!? For that you could simply use the `__COUNTER__` macro. Also note that globals in the same translation unit are guaranteed to be initialized in the order in which they are defined…

Comment: I actually found that counter macro earlier today but that introduces one of the same issues I want to avoid. I don’t want to have to use PROBE(__COUNTER__,...).   I’d like the probe to already have an id, and only an optional name is passed.

Comment: You could make `PROBE()` itself a macro that uses the `__COUNTER__` macro internally. Apart from that, what exactly are your requirements for an id? As I said, if you just need a unique identifier, simply use the address of a global object or function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a member function (which gets a `this` pointer passed as an arg); instead you can simply create constructor-like functions that reference a global array, like

```
#define PROBE(id, stuff, more_stuff) \
  __attribute__((constructor)) void \
  probeinit##id(){ probes[id] = {id, stuff, 0/*to be written later*/, more_stuff}; }
```

The trick is having this macro work in the middle of another function.  GNU C / C++ allows nested functions, but IDK if you can make them constructors.

You don't want to declare a `static int dummy#id = something` because then you're adding overhead to the function you profile.  (gcc has to emit a thread-safe run-once locking mechanism.)

---

Really what you'd like is some kind of separate pass over the source that identifies all the PROBE macros and collects up their args to declare

```
struct probe global_probes[] = {
    {0, "EventName", 0 /*placeholder*/, filename, linenum},
    {1, "EventName", 0 /*placeholder*/, filename, linenum},
    ...
 };
```

I'm not confident you can make that happen with CPP macros; I don't think it's possible to `#define PROBE` such that every time it expands, it *redefines* another macro to tack on more stuff.

But you could easily do that with an awk/perl/python / your fave scripting language program that scans your program and constructs a `.c` that declares an array with static storage.

---

Or better (for a single-threaded program): keep the runtime timestamps in one array, and the names and stuff in a separate array.  So the cache footprint of the probes is smaller.  For a multi-threaded program, stores to the same cache line from different threads is called false sharing, and creates cache-line ping-pong.

So you'd have `#define PROBE(id, evname, blah blah)  do { probe_times[id] = now(); }while(0)`

and leave the handling of the later args to your separate preprocessing.

Comment: Keeping the run time data and static data in separate arrays is a good idea, and I was planning on using a global array. Not quite sure how I would use that macro probeinit##id() ?   How would I get the id?  Do you mean to lilterally call it in the code, or it would already be defined somehow in the probe object before main runs?

Comment: @SubliminalBroccoli: `##id` is CPP concatenation of a macro parameter.  Like I said, that first idea is probably not very workable because it expands wherever you actually put `PROBE()`.